# Handling #Num! in data field

Tags: ms-access

In Access db I have a linked table that references Excel file.

In the Excel file I have 2 columns:

```
Col1    | Col2
---------------
date1   | =if(Col1="","",Col1+1) -> Evaluates to date1+1
<blank> | =if(Col1="","",Col1+1) -> Evaluates to ""
```

In Access I see it as

```
Col1    | Col2
---------------
date1   | date1+1
<null>  | #Num!
```

I can't find a way to deal with the problem. The idea is to end up having `<null>` instead of the error value. Can I capture this error in Access? I have tried looking for error capturing function but I found nothing. I can think of workaround like returning 0 instead of "" and then filtering it out in Access but it doesn't seem like a proper way of doing it. 
I could also use the first column to filter the second but again it doesn't seem proper, because in some other cases I could have just 1 column.

Comment: Col1 contains date? Can you edit formula in excel? As a workaround you can calculate Col2 in Access instead of Excel

Comment: Yes, it's all dates. I find it quite surpizing that there seems to be no workaround-type solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIf evaluates both expressions, and don't mix dates and strings, so try this:

```
=IIf(IsNull(Col1),Null,DateAdd("d",1,Nz(Col1, Date()))
```

or:

```
=CVDate(Col1)+1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This is basically what Sergey S. suggested in the comment. The thing is that it doesn't really capture the error in Access itself and moves the logic from Excel to Access, thus it is based on the premise that it can be done.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You asked: "Can I capture this error in Access?" - and the answer is Yes. It does capture the error in Access. Best thing would, of course, be to clean up the data in Excel before linking the worksheet/range.